# Is there an integrated way to make a Hashmap of a key attribute to the object it belongs to in java?

Tags: java, object, hashmap, key

Say I have a class Student (minimal working example).
 Student has an int attribute `iD`, which in my dataset is unique. Student also has other attributes. I want to store Students in a Map, where I can access them by their `iD`s. What I've currently been doing, is to overwrite `equals()` in Student, so that it only compares the attribute `iD`, also `hashCode()` so that it returns the hashCode of `iD`. Then I create a Hashmap of `<Integer, Student>` where `get(<iD>)` will return the Student with `iD==<iD>`. Now this seems to me a bit redundant and overcomplicated. Is there anything in java Collections perhaps that addresses this use case?

Comment: You could use a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) with a matching implementation of `equals(Object obj)` (and `hashCode()`) in `Student`.

Comment: @Turing85 I stated that I was already doing that. I was asking if there was an _integrated_ way to do this, that didn't require overwriting `equals` and `hashCode` in Student. Same as you don't overwrite `compareTo` but use a `Comparator` when ordering something against its natural ordering

Comment: The *integrated* way is a `HashSet`. There is no possibility to automatically "wire" the `id` of a `Student` to a `HahsMap`-key. Can you explain, which specific problem you are trying to solve? This feels like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Turing85 I have a bunch of classes that all have a an attribute as key, called Index2D. This refers to their locations in a 2D array. Not all positions in this array are taken up though, because the array is a representation of a coordinate system, so instead of having null entries, I thought it would be a good idea to use this attribute, Index2D, to access them, instead of over the array indices. The problem is that in every class I have to overwrite the aforementioned methods. If there is no way other way to access the attribute, I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: If you are not going to use `Student` objects as keys in map and store them in set then you do not need to override `hashCode()` and `equals`. But in this case instead of student.equals(anotherStudent)` you have to use `student.getID().equals(anotherStudent.getID())`.

Comment: @Commodore64 well the easiest thing would be to use indeed a `HashMap`, use the `Index2D` associated with an entity as a key and create a common (possibly abstract) super-class or interface for all your entities. You can define `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` within the superclass/interface (hooray for `default` methods in interfaces!).

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the tip! That does solve my specific problem. I guess My approach to this issue was database-oriented, where you have a key and associated information for an entry, but you access that entry using the key

Comment: @Ivan Oh right, I only need to overwrite the methods if I want to create a reversed Hashmap. (facepalm) Thanks for the help! (I was working with reversed hashmaps before and forgot I didn't even need to reverse these...) The only redundant bit is storing the iD both as a key in the hashmap, and in the object itself

Comment: @Turing85 Just a warning w.r.t. overriding methods from `Object` via default methods in an interface. That's not possible and produces a compilation error.